# Injecting service with JMS\DiExtraBundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, entity, listener

I have service PgHistService in subdirectory Service in DbExtensionBundle:

```
namespace Iba\DbExtensionBundle\Service;
class PgHistService { ...}
```

This service is defined in bundles's services.yml and can be sucessfully included in a controller via $this->get('pghist.service'):

```
parameters:
    pghist.service.class: Iba\DbExtensionBundle\Service\PgHistService

services:            
    pghist.service:
        class: %pghist.service.class%
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Now I want to inject it with JMS\DIExtraBundle in doctrine entity listener:

```
namespace Iba\DbExtensionBundle\Entity;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class BaseEntityListener {
    /** @DI\Inject("pghist.service") */
    public $pgHist;
}
```

Variable pgHist is always null. What am I doing wrong, please? I tried to set this in config.yml but it doesn't work either:

```
jms_di_extra:
   locations:
      all_bundles: false
      bundles: [DbExtensionBundle]
      directories: ["%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/iba/db-extension-bundle/Iba/DbExtensionBundle/Service"]
```

Comment: Is the entity listener actually being triggered?  I don't see a configuration like [described here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#doctrinelistener-or-doctrinemongodblistener)

Comment: Seem you directories conf is point to a location different of your namespace listener

Comment: Hi, Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

Jason Roman is right, thank you.
If you want to use JMS\DiExtraBunde together with entity listener, you have to use DIExtraBundle own system of invoking listener via annotation `@DoctrineListener` in listener instead of Doctrine standard one `@EntityListeners` in the entity.